# Green's Function for Half-Disk

Tags: greens-function, partial-differential-equations

For the semi-disk with domain $$D=[x=(x_{1},x_{2}) \in\mathbb{R}^{2}: \lvert x \rvert^{2} < 1, \ x_{2} > 0 \}$$
how can one find the Green's Function for the upper half $ \ \ 0<r<1, \ 0<\theta<\pi$ using the method of images?

Can I use the general Green's Function for the full disk and subtract an image source at the bottom half of the disk? So probably,

$$\frac{1}{4\pi} \ln( \frac{r^2 + r_0^2 - 2rr_0cos\theta}{r^2r_0^2 + 1 - 2rr_0 cos\theta})-\frac{1}{4\pi} \ln( \frac{r^2 + r_0^2 - 2rr_0cos\theta_0}{r^2r_0^2 + 1 - 2rr_0 cos\theta_0})$$ if $x=(r.cos(\theta),r.sin(\theta))$ and $\xi=(r_0.cos(\theta_0),r_0.sin(\theta_0))$. For a Dirichlet problem, is this sufficient? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542305/greens-function-for-a-semi-circle

Comment: I dont quite understand the answer to that post, I dont want to involve complex analysis here.

Comment: @curiousboi You don't need to know that much complex analysis. It's just a shorthand to simplify notation. Write $y = y_1 + iy_2$, $\bar{y} = y_1 - iy_2$ and plug into the formula. Everything turns out to be real.