# Green function in a half-disk with a slit

Tags: calculus, probability, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I’m trying to calculate the form of the Green function in a half-disk with a slit and I can not figure out the specific formula.

I tried 2 ways, first, I tried to use the equation

$$ \nabla^2 \phi(x,y)=0 $$
$$ \phi(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}log |x-y| $$

But it doesn’t seem to work because I could not figure out what exactly the solution is with a formula.

Second, I tried to use the eigenvectors to calculate it but stilll, nothing ever gets done ‘cause I do not know how to calculate it.

Maybe we could use a martingale to solve it? As I have no clue, I don’t know how to do it.

I put a picture below, the red curves are the boundary of the domain I’m working about.

[image]

Comment: What are your boundary conditions? You may find this link useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542305/greens-function-for-a-semi-circle

Comment: @Dmoreno I’m thinking about the Dirichlet condition. This lint is pretty useful but I’m thinking about the disk with a domain, so I cannot figure out the Green function.